# mysql DATETIME вычисления

Tags: mysql

Делаю запрос:

```
SELECT 
(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 4 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 8 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 9 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 11 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 12 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 13 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 16 MINUTE)-NOW(),
(NOW() + INTERVAL 17 MINUTE)-NOW()
```

Выводит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, что это за формат и как это преобразовать в секунды или более адекватный вид?

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вывести сколько времени прошло с определенной даты, для этого нужно разобраться в каком формате mysql выводит datetime, данный пример показывает, что в каком-то особом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператора вычитания между двумя timestamp в mysql не существует. Вместо этого используется приведение timestamp к числу и далее числовой оператор вычитания.

timestamp приводится к числу как форматирование YYYYMMDDHHIISS. То есть timestamp `2019-08-29 16:21:30` приводится к числу `20190829162130`. И, как следствие, два timestamp с разницей в минуту после приведения к числу получают численную разницу в 100.

Для обработки типов данных дат mysql предлагает [набор штатных функций](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Например, для получения количества секунд между двумя датами можно воспользоваться функцией `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), (NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать сколько времени прошло с определенной даты используется функция [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime_expr_from, datetime_expr_to)
```

т.е. вам нужно вызвать

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, datetime_expr, NOW())
```

получите, сколько прошло минут от `datetime_expr` до текущего времени